# Python unittest fails when it shouldn't

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7

I ran unit tests in the file below, and one of test cases failed, where it should not have failed. I got an unexpected result - Assertion error, where in TestFormatInitMethodArgs I intended to test if `'"' == '"'`, but it tested for `'"' == None` - it looks like test in the second testcase checks for equality from not its own setUp():

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import unittest

class Format:
    def __init__(self, file_path, header=False, flag='r', delimiter=',', quote_char=None):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.header = header
        self.flag = flag
        self.delimiter = delimiter
        self.quote_char = None

class TestFormatInitMethodDefaults(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.file_path = 'C:/Privatus/eurusd.csv'
        self.header = False
        self.flag = 'r'
        self.delimiter = ','
        self.quote_char = None

    def test_attributes(self):
        f = Format('C:/Privatus/eurusd.csv')
        self.assertEqual(self.file_path, f.file_path)
        self.assertEqual(self.header, f.header)
        self.assertEqual(self.flag, f.flag)
        self.assertEqual(self.delimiter, f.delimiter)
        self.assertEqual(self.quote_char, f.quote_char)

class TestFormatInitMethodArgs(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.file_path = 'C:/Privatus/eurusd.csv'
        self.header = True
        self.flag = 'rb'
        self.delimiter = ';'
        self.quote_char = '"'

    def test_args(self):
        a = Format('C:/Privatus/eurusd.csv', header=True, flag='rb', delimiter=';', quote_char='"')
        self.assertEqual(self.file_path, a.file_path)
        self.assertEqual(self.header, a.header)
        self.assertEqual(self.flag, a.flag)
        self.assertEqual(self.delimiter, a.delimiter)
        self.assertEqual(self.quote_char, a.quote_char)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test results:

```
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_args (__main__.TestFormatInitMethodArgs)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Privatus\repos\working\data.py", line 45, in test_args
    self.assertEqual(self.quote_char, a.quote_char)
AssertionError: '"' != None

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not seem to set the `quote_char` attribute in your constructor (`__init__`)

Try `self.quote_char = quote_char` instead of `self.quote_char = None`

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.